# Why does (int)(float.Parse("0.04", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * 100) equals 3

Tags: c#, .net

My boss reported my a bug today because my configuration was decreasing whenever he wanted to specify a value below 5%. I know that I can just round my number before casting it as int to fix my problem, but I don't understand why this problem occurs.

I have a app.config file with the value "0.04" and a configuration section with a float property. When the section is read, the float value retrieved is 0.04, which is fine. I want to put this value in a windows forms TrackBar which accept an integer value so I multiply my value by 100 and a cast it as int. For some reason, the result is not 4, but it's 3. You can test it like this :

```
Console.WriteLine((int)(float.Parse("0.04", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * 100)); // 3
```

What happened?

Comment: Read "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because 0.04 can't be exactly represented as a `float` - and neither can the result of multiplying it by 100. The result is very slightly less than 4, so the cast to int truncates it.

Basically, if you want to use numbers represented accurately in decimal, you should use the `decimal` type instead of `float` or `double`. See my articles on [decimal floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) and [binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) for more information.

EDIT: There's something more interesting going on here, actually... in particular, if you assign the result to a local variable first, that changes the result:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Assign first, then multiply and assign back, then print
        float f = Foo();
        f *= 100;
        Console.WriteLine((int) f); // Prints 4

        // Assign once, then multiply within the expression...
        f = Foo();
        Console.WriteLine((int) (f * 100)); // Prints 4

        Console.WriteLine((int) (Foo() * 100)); // Prints 3
    }

    // No need to do parsing here. We just need to get the results from a method
    static float Foo()
    {
        return 0.04f;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what's going on here, but the exact value of 0.04f is:

```
0.039999999105930328369140625
```

... so it *does* make sense for it not to print 4, potentially.

I *can* force the result of 3 if the multiplication by 100 is performed with `double` arithmetic instead of `float`:

```
f = Foo();
Console.WriteLine((int) ((double)f * 100)); // Prints 3
```

... but it's not clear to me why that's happening in the original version, given that `float.Parse` returns `float`, not `double`. At a guess, the result remains in registers and the subsequent multiplication is performed using `double` arithmetic (which is valid according to the spec) but it's certainly a surprising difference.

Comment: Yes Jon, we know, your [ponies](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) again ... ;)

Comment: "here's something more interesting going on here, actually... still investigating..." hm? I see nothing special here. `f*100` is `4-8,940697E-08` on my system, and gets displayed as `4` because the default `ToString()` conversion neglects the least significant digits. And the rounding errors don't cancel out, because some intermediate results are kept as double/extended.

Comment: Intermediate results can be kept at a higher precision than the static type. AFAIK assigning to a local variable may or may not change that. Explicitly casting to `float` (even if the type is already `float`) on the other hand guarantees degradation of the value to what `float` can represent.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Yes... I believe the results will depend on CLR version and CPU architecture.

Comment: @CodeInChaos assigning to a local variable *does* change that because it causes the compiler to issue an instruction truncating the value to the exact precision of `float`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the float value is really more like 0.039999999999; you are therefore converting a value like 3.99999999999 to int, which yields 3.

You can solve the problem by rounding:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)Math.Round(float.Parse("0.04", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * 100));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not 4 but 3,99999 and lots of other numbers. Do something like this:

```
(int)(float.Parse("0.04") * 100.0 + 0.5)
```

Casting to float is like a floor operator and as this is not exactly 4 it is truncated to 3.

Comment: To add to this, if you need precision and you know it is only 2 decimal places, use the decimal type.

Answer (score 0):

As a float 0.04*100 might well be represented as 3.9999999999, and casting to an int just truncates it, so that is why yo are seeing 3